# HttpClient won't connect on port 993?

Tags: java, apache, http, rest

I had a Tomcat instance setup to listen on port 80xx. It hosts a REST service.
I did the client side tests using WizTools RESTClient 3.2, and it was going fine. Then, I was asked to switch the server's listening port to 993, which is regularly reserved for IMAPS (don't ask why..).

Literally the only thing changed in the setup was the connector port. Now, RESTClient fails with the following exception:

```
Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.wiztools.restclient.HTTPClientRequestExecuter.execute(HTTPClientRequestExecuter.java:387)
at org.wiztools.restclient.ui.RESTViewImpl$2.run(RESTViewImpl.java:322)
```

Subsequently, it showed that `wget`, `curl` and `telnet` work fine on the changed port (993), so it must be a `HttpClient` issue (used in the application).

Can someone tell what could be the reason for this behavior...?

Comment: But you are shure that `your` server runs on 993 and not a mail server? Maybe your server simple does not start (and dies silently).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but yes - Tomcat is definitely up on the port 993, since this port wasn't in use prior to this. As I said , I tested it both locally and remotely using `curl`, `wget`, and `telnet`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried running a bare apache tomcat instance on port `993` and then on `994`.

What I've found is that Google Chrome was able to access `994` but not `993` because its a restricted port for `IMAPS`. (Fun Fact that I didn't know: All browsers block these non-standard HTTP ports because they pose a security risk. For example, you can [view here a list](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/base/net_util.cc) of all restricted ports for Google Chrome if you scroll down to line `94`.)

Using `WizTools RESTClient 3.2.1` for a Mac works for me but this is locally. Depending on your network there could be something going on Network/firewall wise which would be weird because `curl` and etc. are working, So I don't think its an actual issue with `HttpClient` because it should act like `curl` and etc. does. Maybe it is with `3.2` and not `3.2.1`.

See:

[image]

Comment: You're right - browsers do block these non-standard ports. I'll check the newer version of the client, and see what happens.

Comment: Nope, same thing happens with the version 3.2.1. The thing I forgot to mention is that I ran `curl`, `wget`, and `telnet` commands from the bridged guest Ubuntu VM (my host OS is Windows7). So, I tried running `RESTClient` from Ubuntu as well, and guess what - it works fine :) this is something on the OS level, probably firewall, but I couldn't pinpoint the problem. I have to give you at least +1 for effort and the idea to run RC from different OS ;)

Comment: Ubuntu Firewall may be blocking that port. And you said using telnet on Windows to the Ubuntu box worked right?

Comment: There's obviously a misunderstanding here... :) Tomcat is hosted on a remote server with publicly accessible port 993. I (the client) have Windows 7 host, and Ubuntu guest. When running `RESTClient` on Windows host, I fail to reach Tomcat on 993. When using `RESTClient` on Ubuntu guest, it works fine. So, it must be Windows firewall or something, although I haven't spotted the rule that blocks this port. Ubuntu has no FW enabled, whatsoever.

Comment: I understand now. Three OS's in play. Then it's something windows related if it works fine on Ubuntu client. Try disabling your Anti-Virus if you have one.